# Calculate date variables for time series analysis using a dynamic approach

Tags: r, date, dplyr

In the following example, I'd like to calculate the variables `Date_replaced` and `Date_current_until` from `Date` for each customer and product.

`Date_replaced` reflects the timepoint at which a product bought by a certain customer was replaced by the purchase of another sort of product.
`Date_current_until` reflects the timepoint until a product was the current product for each customer.

```
library(dplyr)

Customer_ID <- c(rep(1,4), rep(2,5))
Date <- c(seq(as.Date("2024-02-01"), as.Date("2024-02-04"), "days"), seq(as.Date("2024-02-01"), as.Date("2024-02-05"), "days")) 
Goods <- c(rep("Food",3), "Toys", "Newspaper", rep("Food",3), "Toys")
Date_first_purchased <- c(rep("2024-02-01", 3), "2024-02-04", "2024-02-01", rep("2024-02-02", 3), "2024-02-05") %>% as.Date (., format="%Y-%m-%d") 
Date_replaced <- c(rep("2024-02-04", 3), NA, "2024-02-02", rep("2024-02-05", 3), NA) %>% as.Date (., format="%Y-%m-%d") 
Date_current_until <- c(rep("2024-02-04", 4), "2024-02-02", rep("2024-02-05", 4)) %>% as.Date (., format="%Y-%m-%d")

df <- data.frame(Customer_ID, Date, Goods, Date_first_purchased, Date_replaced, Date_current_until)
```

So far, I've tried the usual things when working on time series data, for instance, grouping data by `ID` and arranging them by `Date` within each `ID`. I also tried using `lead ()` in combination with `mutate` but was not successful as it seems that `lag()` and `lead()` only support fixed numbers to find a previous or subsequent entry. However, this problem obviously requires a dynamic solution which I was not able to find yet. Maybe someone of you has tackled a similar problem previously. Any advice on how to do this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%  
  mutate(Date_replaced = if_else(lead(Goods) != Goods,
                                 lead(Date), 
                                 max(Date[Goods == Goods])), 
         Date_current_until = if_else(row_number() == n(), 
                                      Date, 
                                      if_else(lead(Goods) != Goods,  
                                              lead(Date), 
                                              max(Date[Goods == Goods]))), 
         .by = Customer_ID) 

# A tibble: 9 × 6
  Customer_ID Date       Goods     Date_first_purchased Date_replaced Date_current_until
        <dbl> <date>     <chr>     <date>               <date>        <date>            
1           1 2024-02-01 Food      2024-02-01           2024-02-04    2024-02-04        
2           1 2024-02-02 Food      2024-02-01           2024-02-04    2024-02-04        
3           1 2024-02-03 Food      2024-02-01           2024-02-04    2024-02-04        
4           1 2024-02-04 Toys      2024-02-04           NA            2024-02-04        
5           2 2024-02-01 Newspaper 2024-02-01           2024-02-02    2024-02-02        
6           2 2024-02-02 Food      2024-02-02           2024-02-05    2024-02-05        
7           2 2024-02-03 Food      2024-02-02           2024-02-05    2024-02-05        
8           2 2024-02-04 Food      2024-02-02           2024-02-05    2024-02-05        
9           2 2024-02-05 Toys      2024-02-05           NA            2024-02-05
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a nice and concise solution. At least it seems I was on the right track. 

Could you elaborate a little bit on your solution for ```Date_current_until```? 

For ```Date_replaced```, you're applying ```if_else``` from ```dplyr``` to look for changes in ```Goods```. If the condition is met, you select the subsequent date entry which returns NA for the last product. If the condition is not met, you select the latest date (max) from ```Goods``` grouped by ```ID```. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

HoelR posted a really nice answer. I was working on mine. I tried to imagine a long historic for some Customer; I added an ID for consecutive identical Goods. I check the Date and filling in the "Up" direction

```
  dfx = data.frame(Customer_ID, Date, Goods, Date_first_purchased) %>% 
  group_by(Customer_ID) %>% 
  arrange(Date, Goods, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  # Adding an ID of consecutive (not required on the provided example)
  mutate(consecutive_id = consecutive_id(Customer_ID,Goods) ) %>%
  relocate(consecutive_id, .after= Goods) %>% 
  
  # Checking if the category of product differs from the next.
  # - A Date_replaced will be assigned (the next date) to the last line of the Goods group; NA otherwise
  # - Same for Date_current_until
  mutate( Date_replaced = if_else(  Goods != lead(Goods) , lead(Date), NA ) ) %>% 
  mutate( Date_current_until = if_else(  Goods != lead(Goods) , lead(Date), NA )) %>% 
  
  # Grouping again, preparing the filling
  group_by(Customer_ID, consecutive_id) %>% 
  # Filling in the "up" direction
  fill(c(Date_replaced,Date_current_until), .direction = "up") %>% 
  # Filling an edge case (to confirm). No other product (one or multiple of the same category)
  # has been bought by the Customer.
  mutate( Date_current_until = if_else( is.na(Date_current_until ), Date,  Date_current_until) ) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you! That's also a nice and well commented solution. Works like a charm - much appreciated.